# Non volatile global variables in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a page where users are signing up for a courses. The number of courses is limited. I wanted to store number of available places in global variables for speed and low database load. But if I use either static class or Application["key"] property data is getting lost when application ends due to no users accessing it. Application_End event is not being fired in this case. Is database the only proper way for storing data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use Xml document or Database instead of storing value in Application or static objects/list.

You may use `appSettings` section of web-config to store such details.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with AVD.
For example, you could do the following:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Course Name" value="Course ID" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```